# How do I download image to my laptop path via php?

Tags: php

How to I point this image to be downloaded into my local drive in this C:/Users/AlexBoey/Pictures/images/

```
  $url_to_image = 'http://cleversoft.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/senior-php-developer.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($url_to_image);

$my_save_dir = 'C:/Users/AlexBoey/Pictures/images/';
$filename = basename($url_to_image);
$complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;

$fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You can't download location is handled by browser not by your server.

Comment: PHP script is server-side, not client side. You can't do that.

Comment: Do you mean while the script is running on a remote server or do you mean the script is running on your laptop?
PHP is serverside so you could only try to stream the image to your laptop (as client) as a http response, so you can download it...but I dont really see any benefit from this :D

Answer (score 1):

How about `file_get_contents()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://cleversoft.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/senior-php-developer.jpg');
```

Then `file_put_contents()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
file_put_contents('C:/Users/AlexBoey/Pictures/images/image.jpg', $image);
```

> Update - OK the above is for if you are running the PHP from the laptop itself. That isn't the case. So, in addition to that, you need to header attachment stuff and echo content ($file is the path saved on the server, change the file_put_contents to some temp place on your server, you can `unlink()` it before echoing out):

```
$quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

// you can `unlink($file)` the image saved on the server
echo $image;
```

Comment: Still not saving the php script is running on a cloud sever and wants it to save to my laptop

Comment: How could a PHP script download something to a clients laptop? That would be very bad! Browser is handling this, to make him do this, you have to stream the file to the clients browser. You could use http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php or something like that

Comment: I'm assuming he's running some local XAMPP

Comment: Otherwise yeah, he'd need to header out the download attachment headers then echo the content. Still entirely possible, although in that scenario the end user would select wether to open or save the attachment, and would choose himself where to save